# Para que serve o This no Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando recentemente javascript e estou com um pouco de dúvida em relação ao "this" no javascript, vi que ele pode ser usando tanto em um objeto global ou em uma função mas ainda não consegui entender a real função dele, se puderem me ajudar.

Att.

Comment: @DiegoF parece duplicata dessa questão que vc linkou contudo ela mesma está marcada como duplicada e as duas referências que deveriam ter a resposta lá não parecem responder exatamente a questão sobre `this` já que uma é sobre Java e não Javascript (wtf?) e a outra fala sobre "$(this) vs $this vs this?".

Comment: @BrunoRB não tem problema. Todas ficam vinculadas entre si caso alguém procure, foi exatamente por isso que setei a que já é duplicata. E se você ler a resposta da segunda pergunta, verá que ela responde a esta.